# Cannot install libapache2-mod-php5 because of unmet dependencies

Tags: apache2, php, vagrant

I have a vagrant box that installs php 5.3.28 and most php libraries

```
dpkg -l |grep '^ii' |grep php
ii  php5-cgi                         5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
ii  php5-cli                         5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                      5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-curl                        5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 CURL module for php5
ii  php5-dbg                         5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 Debug symbols for PHP5
ii  php5-fpm                         5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php5-gd                          5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 GD module for php5
ii  php5-gmp                         5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 GMP module for php5
ii  php5-imap                        5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 IMAP module for php5
ii  php5-interbase                   5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 interbase/firebird module for php5
ii  php5-intl                        5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 internationalisation module for php5
ii  php5-ldap                        5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 LDAP module for php5
ii  php5-mcrypt                      5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 MCrypt module for php5
ii  php5-mysql                       5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 MySQL module for php5
ii  php5-odbc                        5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 ODBC module for php5
ii  php5-pspell                      5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 pspell module for php5
ii  php5-recode                      5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 recode module for php5
ii  php5-snmp                        5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 SNMP module for php5
ii  php5-sqlite                      5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 SQLite module for php5
ii  php5-tidy                        5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 tidy module for php5
ii  php5-xmlrpc                      5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 XML-RPC module for php5
ii  php5-xsl                         5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0                 XSL module for php5
```

But when I do 
`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`
I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14) but 5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The `libapache2-mod-php5` Ubuntu package (which you're trying to install) expects the Ubuntu versions of the other PHP packages (e.g. `php5-common`). However, the ones you installed are those `~dotdeb` ones (where did you get them?) and you seem to also have disabled the Ubuntu repositories (as otherwise I think `libapache2-mod-php5` would try to downgrade all the packages to the versions that work with it).

You have two options:

- Do NOT install those `~dotdeb` packages, and install the stock Ubuntu versions instead (again, unsure where you got those `~dotdeb` and why you need them; this is for you to decide, really).
- Install `libapache2-mod-php5` from the same place where you got the ~dotdeb packages, that version should work well with them.

Maybe the issue is that your vagrant box was prebuilt and already includes those ~dotdeb, in which case I would really suggest you get another one that's built with official Ubuntu packages, this will be easier for you to work with.

Comment: I am not sure why it is not installing. They are not stock ubuntu. These are the ones I am trying to install https://gist.github.com/awm086/b20c8633b4431d10e110

Comment: @Ali according to http://www.dotdeb.org/about/: "The packages from Dotdeb should work on Ubuntu, but no additional support will be provided."

Comment: hmm, I am stuck trying to bake php 5.3.28 using dotdeb but still cannot resolve this issue.