# libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: php5-common

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, php

I installed php5.5 and upgrade Ubuntu from 12 to 14. Now the system isn't working. 
I did

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

But got

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4) but 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I resolve it?

The commands I used to install php5.5 were like:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
apt-get install ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
apt-get update
apt-get install php5
apt-get install python-software-properties
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-common php5-mysql php5-xmlrpc php5-cgi php5-curl php5-gd php5-cli php5-fpm php-apc php-pear php5-dev php5-imap php5-mcrypt
```

Comment: I found this http://askubuntu.com/questions/524886/cannot-install-libapache2-mod-php5-because-of-unmet-dependencies but I don't know how to replace the version. Can anyone let me know how to remove 5.5.18+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 and install php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4)??? I think that might solve the problem.

Comment: Are you using unofficial PPAs?

Comment: I don't really know... not a system admin type of guy. I know I installed stock Ubuntu 12 before. I did these to install php 5.5: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable

Comment: apt-get install ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
apt-get update
apt-get install php5
apt-get install python-software-properties
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is that you have an unofficial PPA which is breaking your install procedure.  To remediate this, run the below commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php5
```

This PPA is providing a different (old) version of PHP instead of the proper version that Ubuntu wants.

Run these commands to add the extra repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

Now, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Your repository information will be the official Ubuntu ones. Install `libapache2-mod-php5` using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

**Note:** You may need to uninstall the old PHP packages first. Command:

```
sudo apt-get remove php5 php5-common php5-mysql php5-xmlrpc php5-cgi php5-curl php5-gd php5-cli php5-fpm php-apc php-pear php5-dev php5-imap php5-mcrypt
```

---

***You should not add PPAs unless you absolutely need them.*** They can break more than they solve and can cause problems like this. Also, unofficial PPAs are attack vectors for potential viruses. Unless you really need to use a PPA, don't.

Comment: Absolutely agreed, it even broke apache2! Many thanks

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository universe` It is failing `Error: 'universe' invalid`

Comment: @VivekVardhan Please [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) so we can better help you and keep this comment thread clean. Thanks! Feel free to cross-link to this answer if you feel that it's relevant enough.

Comment: For `Error: 'universe' invalid` see http://askubuntu.com/a/227788/41229

Comment: `E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate`