# Getting error to configure php5 mysql packges

Tags: 14.04, mysql, php, ppa, lamp

I am trying to configure LAMP stack on ubntu14.04 using [Digital Ocean Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04). apache2 configured properly but when I am running below command its throwing error.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql
```

**Error**

> Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ trusty/main php5-common amd64 5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
>     404  Not Found

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ trusty/main php5-mysql amd64 5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-common_5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-mysql_5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

Also I tried to install php5-common packge using below command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-common=5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4
```

But its tried to install package `php5-json` but that also return 404 error. Please help me to get this done. I want to install `php5.6` version not `php7`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I discovered why I am getting this error. I have an unofficial PPA which is breaking my install procedure. [this Answer helped me to get it done](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540423/libapache2-mod-php5-depends-php5-common).

Apart from that I have installed many `php5-*` modules using package version. For example I have installed php5-common package using below command

`sudo apt-get install php5-common=5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4`